# How to build python extension module with waf on windows/visual studio?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, swig, waf

I'm trying to figure out how to build a python extension module using [waf](https://waf.io/) but I've got stuck. Consider a simple tree such as:

**foo.h**

```
#pragma once

class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
  const int &a() const;
  int &a();

private:
  int m_a;
};

inline const int &Foo::a() const { return m_a; }

inline int &Foo::a() { return m_a; }
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo() : m_a(0) {}
```

**foo.i**

```
%module foo

%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

%include "foo.h"
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.h"

using namespace std;
int main() {
  Foo foo;
  cout << foo.a() << endl;
  foo.a() = 10;
  cout << foo.a() << endl;
}
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('build')

from foo import Foo

foo = Foo()
print foo.a
foo.a = 1
print foo.a
```

**wscript**

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path


def configure(conf):
    conf.env.MSVC_VERSIONS = ["msvc 15.0"]
    conf.env.MSVC_TARGETS = ["x86"]
    conf.load("msvc python swig")
    conf.check_python_version((3, 6, 8))

    # This method is not working properly on windows/virtualenv
    # conf.check_python_headers()

    # Maybe something like this could help?
    # from distutils import sysconfig
    # print(sysconfig.get_python_inc())

    conf.check_swig_version()


def build(bld):
    bld.program(source=["main.cpp", "foo.cpp"], cxxflags=["/EHsc"], target="test")

    bld.shlib(
        features="cxx",
        source="foo.cpp",
        target="foo",
        includes=".",
        export_includes=".",
        name="FOO",
    )

    # bld.program(
    #     source = 'main.cpp',
    #     target = 'main',
    #     use = ['FOO'],
    #     rpath = ['$ORIGIN'],
    # )

    # bld(
    #     features = 'cxx cxxshlib pyext',
    #     source = 'foo.i',
    #     target = '_foo',
    #     swig_flags = '-c++ -python -Wall',
    #     includes = '.',
    #     use  = 'FOO',
    #     rpath = ['$ORIGIN', ],
    #  )


def run(bld):
    root_path = Path(bld.path.abspath())
    subprocess.run(str(root_path / "build/test.exe"))
```

The first issue I'm already facing here is when I do `waf distclean configure build`, I'll get this error:

```
(py382_64) D:\swigtest>waf distclean configure build
'distclean' finished successfully (0.006s)
Setting top to                           : D:\swigtest
Setting out to                           : D:\swigtest\build
Checking for program 'CL'                : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe
Checking for program 'CL'                : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe
Checking for program 'LINK'              : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\LINK.exe
Checking for program 'LIB'               : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\LIB.exe
Checking for program 'MT'                : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86\MT.exe
Checking for program 'RC'                : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86\RC.exe
Checking for program 'python'            : d:\virtual_envs\py368_32\scripts\python.exe
Checking for program 'swig'              : D:\software\swig\swig.exe
Checking for python version >= 3.6.8     : 3.6.8
Checking for swig version                : 4.0.0
'configure' finished successfully (1.538s)
Waf: Entering directory `D:\swigtest\build'
[1/5] Compiling foo.cpp
[2/5] Compiling main.cpp
[3/5] Compiling foo.cpp
foo.cpp

foo.cpp

[4/5] Linking build\foo.dll
main.cpp

[5/5] Linking build\test.exe
Waf: Leaving directory `D:\swigtest\build'
Build failed
-> missing file: 'D:\\swigtest\\build\\foo.lib'
```

**QUESTION**: How can I fix that little issue? In any case, my main question here would be what's the proper way to generate a python extension module with [swig](http://swig.org/) and waf on windows?

Comment: I would recommend that you start without the `waf` thing and understand what swig is. You are supposed to generated c++ wrapper source and not just produce a simple dll from your class Foo.

Comment: Why are you assuming I haven't used swig before... in fact, I've used swig over the years 1) manually 2) with setuptools 3) with custom build sytem 4) with cmake ... So now I'm just trying to understand how to use it with `waf` . Unfortunately the little examples you'll see out there on github are broken or just working on unix...  And yeah, I know you need to generate the c++ wrapper but before reaching that point (you'll see commented code) I was trying to figure out some previous requisites ;)

Comment: Your output does not say anything about generating wrapper - only compiling foo.cpp, main.cpp and linking foo.dll. Again, I recommend that you look at what is been done under the hood and compare it to solving the wrapping without waf.

Comment: Mmm, from your comment it's become clear to me my question isn't reaching properly to the audience. Ok, tomorrow if I find the time I'll post the steps how you'd compile this simple stuff manually and what'd be the proper way to translate those steps into waf. And yeah, I want to use waf mainly because the real project I'm trying to wrap is very complex, with several dependencies... which it's where waf should shine :)

Comment: Good idea. Small project using perhaps CMake or Python's distutils and your work in progress using waf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your current build by changing the library type from shared (`shlib`) to static (`stlib`), i.e.

```
def build(bld):
    bld.program(source=["main.cpp", "foo.cpp"], cxxflags=["/EHsc"], target="test")

    bld.stlib(
        features="cxx",
        source="foo.cpp",
        target="foo",
        includes=".",
        export_includes=".",
        name="FOO",
    )
```

To build the python extension module, you can use this:

```
def build(bld):
    bld.program(source=["main.cpp", "foo.cpp"], cxxflags=["/EHsc"], target="test")

    bld.stlib(
        features="cxx",
        source="foo.cpp",
        target="foo",
        includes=".",
        export_includes=".",
        name="FOO",
    )

    bld(
        features = 'cxx cxxshlib pyext',
        source = 'foo.i',
        target = '_foo.pyd',
        swig_flags = '-c++ -python -Wall',
        includes = '.',
        use = 'FOO',
    )
```

This will output a dll library into a file named `_foo.pyd` and a python script `foo.py`.
I'm not claiming that this is the proper way, but it worked for me.

Also, when using the extension (e.g. `from foo import Foo`) do make sure that these files are on python's search path (using `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path.append`), otherwise you might get errors such as:

- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_foo'
- ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _foo: The parameter is incorrect.

I got the second error when I've tried running your `main.py` directly from the main directory and resolved it by using an absolute (instead of relative) path in the `sys.path.append` call in `main.py`.

**Edit**
I was using python 3.8.5 and Visual Studio 2017
Below is the full wscript. 
You'll need to change the path to the Python headers and libraries referenced in CXXFLAGS, LDFLAGS (although I guess that there's a better way to configure it)

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

def configure(conf):
    conf.env.MSVC_VERSIONS = ["msvc 15.9"]
    conf.env.MSVC_TARGETS = ["x64"]
    conf.env.append_value('CXXFLAGS', ["/Id:\\tools\\Python38\\include"])
    conf.env.append_value('LDFLAGS', ["/LIBPATH:d:\\tools\\Python38\\libs"])
    conf.load("msvc python swig")
    conf.check_python_version((3, 6, 8))

    # This method is not working properly on windows/virtualenv
    #conf.check_python_headers()

    # Maybe something like this could help?
    # from distutils import sysconfig
    # print(sysconfig.get_python_inc())

    conf.check_swig_version()


def build(bld):
    bld.program(source=["main.cpp", "foo.cpp"], cxxflags=["/EHsc"], target="test")

    bld.stlib(
        features="cxx",
        source="foo.cpp",
        target="foo",
        includes=".",
        export_includes=".",
        name="FOO",
    )

    bld(
        features = 'cxx cxxshlib pyext',
        source = 'foo.i',
        target = '_foo.pyd',
        swig_flags = '-c++ -python -Wall',
        includes = '.',
        use = 'FOO',
    )



def run(bld):
    root_path = Path(bld.path.abspath())
    subprocess.run(str(root_path / "build/test.exe"))
```

**Edit 2**
Initially I was getting the error mentioned in the comments, but now I see that I inadvertadly worked around the [bug that you've reported](https://gitlab.com/ita1024/waf/-/issues/2350#note_563128656) by moving the module declaration in `foo.i` from top to the bottom of the file.

```
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

%include "foo.h"

%module foo
```

Comment: I've tried to run your example but it's not working for me, it tells me something like `Unable to open file D:\swigtest\build\foo.swigwrap_3.cxx: Invalid argument`. I'm trying to run this script using a virtualenv btw... Anyway, could you please post your full wscript so I can reproduce over here? Also... this one `conf.check_python_headers()` wasn't working properly over here. Which python version, visual studio version you're using?

Comment: Thanks, here's a little [modification](https://bpa.st/UO4A) of your script, I guess that's not either the proper way to find python include/libs but it's better than having hardcoded paths.. In any case, for some reason when I run `waf build` is telling me `Unable to open file D:\swigtest\build\foo.swigwrap_2.cxx: Invalid argument` and the wrapper code hasn't been generated in the build folder. Tomorrow I'll continue looking at this, your answer already deserves +1 though

Comment: Here's the session [error](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/aazrci3pkbw260s/ConEmu_2021-04-28_23-55-48.png)

Comment: I've researched more about it and here's my [finding](https://gitlab.com/ita1024/waf/-/issues/2350#note_563128656), I wonder why you're not getting that error though :/

Comment: The bug I've mentioned has been fixed upstream

Comment: Little note, with the new fix [at](https://gitlab.com/ita1024/waf/-/merge_requests/2324) you won't need to move the module declaration to the bottom. Just make sure you're using that particular versio nof waf ;)